# Posts published last 10 minutes

Tags: wp-query, date-time

i have a "featured" section on home page.
i want to hide this section after 10 minutes of post publish time.
here is the code, i am using. 
problem is that it hide the "featured" section after 12 hours of post publish time

------- index.php -------

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1, // We are showing only one post
    'category_name' => 'featured_post' // showing form category prime
                        );

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' ); ?>

<?php
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :?>
 <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="featured_post">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

------- Function.php -------

```
 function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
 // posts published last 30 minutes
 $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-10 minutes')) . "'";
 return $where;
 }
```

---

please guide me.